# 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key' when creating a Non Clustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, snapshot

See below timeline:

1 - 04:58 (Server A) - REORG of PK index on Table1 in DB_XXX started.

2 - 05:00 (Server A) - Create SNAPManager copy of DB_XXX

3 - 05:01 (Server B) - SNAPManager restore of DB_XXX_Copy.

4 - 05:11 (Server A) - REORG of PK index on Table1 in DB_XXX Complete.

*Note: SNAP copy taken mid REORG.*

5 - 05:25 (Server B) - CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX on Table1 failed with the following error: "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Table1' and the index name 'NonClusteredIndex'. The duplicate key value is (111, 222)."

- Firstly, The error suggests the index being created is a UNIQUE INDEX, however the error is generated when running a CREATE NONCLUSTERED statement.
- Secondly, The Duplicate Key error references 2 values (111,222), but the PK is on one column and the NON CLUSTERED INDEX is on one column.

The only thing I can think of is that because the SNAP copy was taken in the middle of a REORG, the PK on this table was in an inconsistent state on the copy? Here is a link to a similar issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398348/unique-index-error-when-creating-non-unique-index-sql-server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398348/unique-index-error-when-creating-non-unique-index-sql-server)

Is anyone able to explain or verify this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: `UNIQUE` and `CLUSTERED`/`NONCLUSTERED` are two separate dimensions, so I'm not sure why you're thinking the `NONCLUSTERED` somehow automatically implies something about uniqueness.

Comment: So did you run `DBCC CHECKTABLE` as mentioned in the other question, and did it give your table a clean bill of health?

Comment: No, in this case we re ran the SNAP copy / restore process. This time the REORG would not have been running. The CREATE NONCLUSTERED index was then successful on the copy.

Comment: Note that anything capable of making a table *inconsistent* is considered a serious bug by the SQL Server development team, irrespective of what statements you run. Even in the middle of an index reorganization that's inserting rows, creating an index should not fail. If you can repro this and if `DBCC CHECKTABLE` *does* indicate a problem, you've got something that you might want to open a Connect issue for, even if you can work around it. (If there is no `CHECKTABLE` issue and the SNAP copy is just doing it wrong, that's another matter.)

Comment: You cannot create an index while a reorganization is running on the same table. They take incompatible locks (schema modification locks). The stated timeline shows that they weren't done at the same time as well.

Comment: Since this was on the secondary, it sounds like the database was left in an inconsistent state. If your files are stored on different drives, you need to make sure that the storage system is configured to take a consistent image of the files together. This type of inconsistency is caused by storage not being configured correctly.

Comment: I believe that the error references uniqueness because the data was inconsistent causing the primary key columns to be repeated The clustered index key columns are included in nonclustered indexes as row identifiers and must be unique. If the clustered index is not unique, it adds a uniquifier where needed. Because a PK is defined as unique, it doesn't try to add a uniquifier thus the error.